# PHP Symfony 6.3.5: Cannot call default session handler when creating a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session

I am creating a form using createForm() with Symfony 6.3.5

```
$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, new Contacts);
$form->handleRequest($request);

return $this->render('Contacts/BlankSlate.html.twig', [
    'active' => 'Contacts',
    'form' => $form
]);
```

When the form is rendered I get the following error:

> Cannot call default session handler

I have created a form type called "ContactType":

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
    }
}
```

I have tried creating forms manually as well as with the form builder. I have also tried writing and reading from the request session and get the same error. When I use $_SESSION everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should call createView method:

```php
<?php

$form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, new Contacts);

return $this->render('Contacts/BlankSlate.html.twig', [
    'active' => 'Contacts',
    'form' => $form->createView(),
]);
```

UPDATE:
Maybe it comes from your configuration. Here's what you can check:

1. PHP Configuration: Ensure that the PHP session module is correctly configured. Check your php.ini file to make sure that the session settings are correct, especially those related to session.save_handler and session.save_path.
2. Permissions: If you're using the default session handler (files), make sure the directory set in session.save_path has write permissions for the web server. Permission issues are a common cause for such an error.
3. Symfony Configuration: Check that the session configuration in your config/packages/framework.yaml (or the appropriate file) is correct.
   Here's a default configuration example:

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

If you're using another session handler (like Redis or a database), ensure that handler is properly configured and operational.

4. Dependencies: Ensure you have all necessary dependencies installed, especially if you're using a session handler other than the default file. For instance, if you're using Redis for sessions, ensure the PHP Redis package and the appropriate Symfony library are installed.
5. Debugging: Use the Symfony web profiling tool (Web Profiler) for more insights into the error. This can give you additional clues about where the problem lies.
6. Logs: Check the Symfony logs for further details on the error. These insights can often point directly to the problem.

Comment: I am using 6.3.5 so using createView() shouldn't do anything but I tried anyway and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Great! Thanks for answering my question. Your update did the trick. The problem indeed came from the Symfony configuration

Comment: Great @exoexo ! Mark it as solved for other people then